# Call method by name in loop iterating by objects, looking for design pattern

Tags: c#, exception, design-patterns, foreach, delegates

I need to advice or idea on how to implement the following. I have an interface with lots of methods each can throw exception (in fact it is WCF call). So the each call **must be** wrapped by try block

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
 MethodThatCanThrow1(Arg1 arg);
 ..
 MethodThatCanThrow101(Arg2 arg);
}
```

Now we have a collection of objects

```
var items = new List<ISomeInterface>();
```

Now I have to call **MethodThatCanThrow1** method in loop for every object. Method can throw exception, in that case I need to continue for remaining ojects

```
void CallMethodThatCanThrow1()
{ 
 foreach(var item in items)
 {
  try
  {
    item.MethodThatCanThrow1(Arg1 arg);
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
   // do something
  }
 }
}
```

Now I need to call **MethodThatCanThrow2** So for second method I need to copypaste the try catch block stuff.

```
void CallMethodThatCanThrow2()
{ 
 foreach(var item in items)
 {
  try
  {
    item.MethodThatCanThrow2(Arg2 arg);
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
   // remove failed item from items
   // continue foreach for the rest
  }
 }
}
```

So for the rest 101 method I have to copy paste the whole block only changing the method name.

So I am thinking about refactoring it. What I want is put try catch block in separate Methodand pass the Method Name that needs to be called

```
void CallMethodofISomeInterfaceForGivenReference(delegate methodProvide)
{ 
 foreach(var item in items)
 {
  try
  {
     // take item and call method that is provided
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
   // do something
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Note: in foreach loop you cannot modify the list.

Comment: @ferikeem I never said I am modifying the list, this is of no importance here

Comment: You could deal with exceptions with a helper method, maybe `void Ignore(Action callback){ ... callback(); ... }` then `foreach(var item ...) Ignore(() => item.MethodThatCanThrow1(a));`. But should you??

Comment: You've already outlined a solution, so what's your question?

Comment: Mark I outline the the idea as I cannot pass a method name and call it for given reference at least I dont know any language construct

Comment: @CaptainComic You could with reflection but that's completely unneccessary because you can pass a delegate. For example you can have a `void TryCatchWrapper(Action action)`. Or you could work with an Expression, so you can use a lambda, even ...

Comment: ^^ See https://dotnetfiddle.net/uczmrI for a naive example.

Comment: @Fildor is right: why pass a method name, which isn't type-safe, instead of a delegate, which *is* type-safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already suggested in comments: Instead of using reflection and method names, I'd use delegates.

Given, your interface has plenty of methods in this form:

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
  void MethodThatCanThrow1(Arg1 arg);
   ..
  void MethodThatCanThrow101(Arg2 arg);
}
```

You could make a little Helper:

```
void TryCatchWrap<TParam1>( Action<TParam1> action, TParam1 param1, Action<Excpetion> handleException )
{
    try
    {
        action(param1);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        handleException(ex)
    }
}
```

that would be called as:

```
foreach( var item in collection )
{
    tryCatchWrap<Arg1>( item.MethodThatCanThrow1, arg, HandleException )
}
```

..., where `HandleException` would be a `void HandleException(Exception ex)` available in that context.

---

You can also adapt this to multiple params, param lists or Funcions with little effort:

```
TResult TryCatchWrap<TParam1, TResult>( Func<TParam1, TResult> action, TParam1 param1, Action<Excpetion> handleException )
{
    try
    {
        return action(param1);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        handleException(ex)
    }
    return default(TResult); // in case of Exception.
}
```

---

Out of curiosity, I tried out if I managed to put the loop in the `try`.

This is what I got:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Arg1 arg = new Arg1();
        // Some test data
        IList<IMyType> list = Enumerable
                               .Range(0, 42)
                               .Select(x => (IMyType)new MyType(x))
                               .ToList();
        
        var p = new Program();
        p.CollectionTryParseWrapper<IMyType, Arg1>(list, arg,          
                              (item, argument) => item.DoSomething(argument));
    }
    
    // Pass Expression instead of delegate so we can loop.
    // Pass argument awkwardly to avoid closure.
    public void CollectionTryParseWrapper<TInterface, TArgument>(
                                                IList<TInterface> list,
                                                TArgument arg1,
                                                Expression<Action<TInterface, TArgument>> expr)
    {
        // compile the Expression to an executable delegate
        var exec = expr.Compile();
        // In case of Exception, we need to know where to continue.
        int index = 0;
        // Just loop
        while(index < list.Count){
            try
            {
                for( ; index < list.Count; index++ )
                {
                    exec(list[index], arg1); // execute
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                // handle ex
                Console.WriteLine("Exception" + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                index++; // advance index!!
            }
        }
    }
}

public interface IMyType
{
    void DoSomething(Arg1 arg);
}

public class Arg1 {
    public bool ShouldThrow(int index) => index % 5 == 0;
}

public class MyType : IMyType
{
    private readonly int _index;

    public MyType(int index)
    {
         this._index = index;
    }

    public void DoSomething(Arg1 arg)
    {
         if( arg.ShouldThrow(_index) ) throw new Exception($" at index {_index}");
         Console.WriteLine($"Executing #{_index:#0}");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception at index 0
Executing #01
Executing #02
Executing #03
Executing #04
Exception at index 5
Executing #06
Executing #07
Executing #08
Executing #09
Exception at index 10
Executing #11
Executing #12
Executing #13
...
```

See in Action: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WjoSZF

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @Fildor This is quite simple but I was stuck in this

Comment: I wonder if this is possible to place foreach inside TryCatchWrap

Comment: That would need some more effort. I guess your goal is to minimize the trycatch-Context creation overhead? I was thinking about this, too, initially. But: That would need you to not only catch the exception but also to figure which item (at which index in the collection) it occurred, then start over from index+1. Certainly doable, but I'd do it only if this runs into actual performance issues.

Comment: @CaptainComic Added a naive attempt to the answer.